# Angular2 - [(ngModel)] With empty object

Tags: angular

I have a form with various inputs, options, and selects. The form is divided into various sections across several components. For example:

```
order.orderInfo.customerName
order.orderInfo.address
order.model.size
order.model.options
order.trims.selectedTrims
```

If `Order = {}` then it crashes with undefined errors. My first thought was to use the elvis operator, but Angular doesn't let you use it in an assignment. The only "solution" I've found so far is to not use the `[(ngModel)]` syntactic sugar at all and instead decompose everything to:

```
<input [ngModel]="order?.orderInfo?.customer_mtm" (ngModelChange)="order.orderInfo.customer_mtm=$event" customer_mtm type="text">
```

Here's the thing, I *must* be doing something very wrong, because it doesn't make much sense to never ever be able to use the `[(ngModel)]` syntax, which is where I'm at now.

Should I just change all my code to the `[ngModel]/(ngModelChange)` syntax, or should I did I get something conceptually wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a few ways around this, but here's how I've seen it done.

In your controller, you create a base object as a constant. For you that would be:

```
const ORDER_BASE = { someprop : 'somedefaultval', ... }
```

This base should satisfy all the requirements you would otherwise use an elvis operator for. When you set the value for the model in the constructor (not ngInit, or you will get undefined errors), you go:

```
this.order = Object.assign ( {}, ORDER_BASE );
```

(this makes a copy of the object so you aren't using the base reference as a model).

Alternatively, you use a factory-ish function:

```
this.order = makeFreshOrder ( );

makeFreshOrder ( ) {
     return Object.assign ( {}, ORDER_BASE );
}
```

This gets you out of messing with elvis operators, worrying about what properties are available on init, and so on.

I try to keep the logic in the markup to a minimum, and a couple of places I've worked, that's the best practice. Don't do anything other than really simple decisioning/checking/validating in the markup with ternary expressions (which gets unwieldy), do it in the controller.

(Note that the base object can be a new instance of an "Order" class...typing this sort of thing can be useful).

I've actually been told, in markup, "if you're using the elvis operator, you're being lazy." Not sure about that one way or another, but I do understand the point.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it crashed is you were accessing "2 level" properties of `order` object (`order?.orderInfo?.customer_mtm`). It will work if you access only 1 level (`like order.orderInfo`).

This makes sense because let imagine you run this code in javascript `var a = {}; a.something works` but you can't do `a.something1.something2` because `something1` is `undefined`.

Now back to your problem, my suggestion is either create a child component and pass your `order` object to it or you can create an empty `order` object in constructor.

Something like

```
var order = {};
order.orderInfo = {};
```

Hope it makes sense.